# Searching comma related value with FIND_IN_SET with multiple search string Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, find-in-set

I am using FIND_IN_SET to get similar comma related values from database the problem what i am facing is if in string i am passing single value it is searching accurately but if i am sending multiple value in string it is not able to search

```
$search  = "FIND_IN_SET('".$toteach."', level_whometoteach)";
$this->db->where($search);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $result = $query->result();
```

If here  $toteach=5 and in level_whometotech 5 is present it search and give result but if,

```
$teach=5,6 and level_whometoteach contains 5,6 no value is returned
```

Can i know the right way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `FIND_IN_SET` will check for individual values separated by comma. In your case, you should use `IN` clause.

Try this query.

```
    $search  = "level_whometoteach IN (".$toteach.")";
    $this->db->where($search);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result();
```

Comment: waaaao its working super just as i wanted thanks alot buddy @AJ

Comment: hi i am facing a problem when entering non comma related value like sometime in string i get comma related value and some time non comma related value so what should i do in this case , now for comma related value it is showing correct output but for non coma related it is not showing any output what should i do ? @A J

Comment: for non-comma separated you can try equality operator.

Comment: how should i check when cooma related value is coming and when normal value ?